# Deploy my Django project in my private network

Tags: django, deployment, ip, local-network

I have created my django project and now I need to deploy the project in my network (DNC IP address) the IP address for example 10.xxx.005.xxx the main point is to let all the employees can access with the same IP and the IP address not connected to the internet it is only local network

The way how to deploy my privet local network and make it accessible how is in the same network